# Jquery AppendTo bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, appendto

I'm working with some jquery and found a weird behaviour of jquery `.appendTo()` function.

Look this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ncog7ccw/1/).

When you click on each item of the first column, the clicked item is appended to the second column.

If you click items `3` and `4`, everything will work as expected: They will be appended in the order you clicked them.
When you click on item `1`, he will be appended correctly too.

The problem is when you click on item `2`. This item is inside the item `1`.

This item is not appended to the end of the div, he' is appended on top of his old parent!

Look the images:

[image: Step by step]

Now, what I was expecting versus what I get:

[image: Expected vs real]

If you click again on item `2` he will be appended at the end of the div.

This behaviour have some explanation? It's a bug in fact?

How can I workaround this?

Ps: Jquery `1.10.1`

Comment: Post some code illustrating this behaviour

Comment: I posted an fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ncog7ccw/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you click on item 2, a "click" event is sent to **both** item 2 **and** item 1, because item 2 (when the "click" happens) is a child of item 1. The event bubbles up and the parent gets it too.

Thus, you click on item 2, and the event handler runs. Item 2 is appended to the target. Then the event bubbles to item 1, and the event handler runs again. Now, item 1 is appended *after* item 2, because (at this point) item 2 is no longer a child of item 1.

**Verdict:** not a bug.

You can change your handler to prevent that:

```
$('.item').on('click', function(e){
    // Append clicked item on destiny div
    $(this).appendTo($('.destiny'));
    e.stopPropagation(); // stop the event from bubbling further up
});
```